# I need to have a custom dialog in Preferences

Tags: android

I want to have a custom dialog (created using layout) in `Preferences`. What should I do to declare this custom dialog in my preferences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement a [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) for your custom layout and add that preference to your preference screen

Here is a good explanation of how to do this:
[Concise way of writing new DialogPreference classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes)

Comment: Cool. Do you know how to hook this new class to SharedPreferences themselves?

Comment: The StackOverflow answer I linked explains how to persist data using either helper methods or SharedPreferences

Comment: Sorry, there is no a single work how to refer to the new class from your xml where you declare preference items.

Comment: In the XML, you must use the full name (including package) of your class that extends DialogPreference. See sample XML here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516022/android-launch-a-custom-preference-from-a-preferenceactivity