# Android Edit Text Preference with own layout with no newValue on onPreferenceChange

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences

I've got  with my own layout.

I would like to receive the text from the editText after positive button on the layout is clicked. But in onPreferenceChange, I always get only the default value.

It seems that I need to bind my own EditText to the preferences somehow, but I don't know how and where to do this.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

First of all, in PreferenceScreen, you need to state:
     <full.path.to.your.OwnLayoutClass
       android:name="whatevever"
       android:dialogLayout="@layout/your_own_layout" />

your_own_layout can be anything you'd like, linearlayout with of buttons, editTexts, according to your wishes.

Essential is the class representing your own preference Dialog. Here is a simple example of how to do it:

```
public class YourOwnLayoutClass extends DialogPreference {

    private LinearLayout mView;

    public YourOwnLayoutClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.your_own_layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        mView = (LinearLayout) view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            // get value from editFields, do whatever you want here :)
            // you can acces them through mView variable very easily
        }
    }
}
```

Important references:
[I need to have a custom dialog in Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456629/i-need-to-have-a-custom-dialog-in-preferences)

[Concise way of writing new DialogPreference classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes)

[Android: launch a custom Preference from a PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516022/android-launch-a-custom-preference-from-a-preferenceactivity)